# How can I pause and resume an observable on document click?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an observable that emits certain values to the console on every second. I show an example below and a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/interview-exercise-1-observable?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) as well.

My dilemma is I need to able to pause it on the next document click and resume it (not restart it) it on the next one again. I was looking into switchMap and I couldn't figure out how to implement it.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "my-app";
  pageClickObservable: Observable<Event> = fromEvent(document, "click");

  ngOnInit(): void {
    new Observable();

    const watchForClick = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("A");
      }, 1000);
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("BB");
        console.log("10");
      }, 2000);
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("CCC");
      }, 3000);
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("DDDD");
        console.log("20");
      }, 4000);
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("EEEEE");
      }, 5000);
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("FFFFFF");
        console.log("30");
      }, 6000);
    };

    this.pageClickObservable.pipe().subscribe(() => {
      watchForClick();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick steer from a volunteer editor - chatty phrases like greetings, thanks, and hopes tend to be removed here. It's not personal - it reflects the general desire to make questions and answers a bit more like documentation or an online encyclopedia.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
const $myContinuousObs = ...... // This is your observable that keeps emitting
const $isOn = new BehaviourSubject(true); // BehaviorSubject to store the current on/off state

combineLatest([$myContinuousObs, $isOn]).pipe( //combine the two
    filter(res => res[1]), // only continue when $isOn is true
    map(res => res[0]) // return only the myContinuousObs and not the $isOn
).subscribe(console.log) // log the value
```

To change `$onOff`:

```
$isOn.next(true)
$isOn.next(false)
```

To toggle `$onOff`

```
$isOn.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(val => $onOff.next(!val))
```

Comment: I reworked ti to use your solution, but I'm confused with thte last one. I can't figure out that last part. See here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ztjjya?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The `$myContinuosObs` should be the observable that emits every second. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kprdt9?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: The problem is that you're changing the requirement to make it fit your code. I don't need to console.log the timestamp. I need to emit exactly 'A' on 1 second, 'BB', 10' on 2nd second, 'CCC' on 3rd second, 'DDDD', '20' on 4th second, etc. This shows that the messages can be fully controlled. They can be a simple conole log, or they can be a notification, or set of instructions etc

Comment: Just put whatever you have, need or want in a observable en replace the timer with it

Comment: Think of it this way, imagine this program to be inside of a robot and you want the robot to: 'console log that he started on second one, make an http request on second 2 for data, process and emit values to another function on second 3, collect the results and send a notifcation on second 4, finish with a message on second 5, put himself in sleep mode on second 6. These are all actions that are different on ever case scenario. This is just an example. not a real thing. But close to what they do

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c82aj4?file=src/app/app.component.ts I replaced the timer with the console logs. It still doens t work

Comment: please recheck my example

Comment: Sorry man, it doesn't work. It is console logging as soon as the page loads and it doesn't pause and resume. This is obviously more difficult than it seemed

Comment: Well you asked a generic solution to something that seems to be a specific problem

Comment: Actually I asked for the specific solution. But it doesn't matter anymore. I got the job anyway. I was just curious as if anyone actually knew how to solve this. Apparently, no one. So that makes me feel better. Thanks anyway. I do appreciate your time. I unfortunately can't award the bounty without a solution

Answer (score 0):

you need to turn your page click into some stream that can track the state of the switch using `scan` like so:

```
const clickStream$ = fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
  scan((isOn, click) => !isOn, true), // on every click, toggle the switch
  startWith(true) // initially emit true
)
```

then you can just `switchMap`:

```
clickStream$.pipe(
  switchMap(isOn => isOn ? obs$ : EMPTY)
).subscribe(v => console.log(v, 'got value'))
```

where `obs$` is whatever you want to start and stop listening to. now this method with `switchMap` will resubscribe on each `clickStream$` emission, which depending on the nature of the observable of interest, may not be what you're after, but the concept of the `clickStream$` observable may still be useful to you combined with the other answer here using `filter`

Comment: I reworked a StackBlitz with your code but I can't figure out what I am missing. See here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qinxed?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: the problem with your stack blitz is that you set `obs$` to also be a document click so the click trigger and the observable of interest are kind of in conflict there. check this revised using `interval` instead: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xkoxct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Close but not exactly what I need. This restarts the sequence. it should pause it and resume from where it was paused, not restart the subscrtiption

Comment: see my note about how you may need to combine this with the other answer using filter. but one thing you say doesn't track, the filter method won't "resume from where it was paused", that will cause you to miss any emissions during the pause period. what you're saying now implies that the subject is aware of it's subscribers (and stop emitting while "paused"), which should not be the case. if you don't want to miss any emissions, you'll need some listener that gathers emissions while paused and holds them for you.

Comment: Quite honestly, I don't understand Observers that microscopically. If you dont have time to provide an answer or it's too cumbersome, I understand. Thanks for your help anyway. I thought it was an easy solution

Comment: the solution isn't all that cumbersome here, the requirements are somewhat unclear. i have no idea what you're actually trying to accomplish or why.

Comment: It was a job exercise. I already got the job, but I was still curious as to how to do it. It emitts the console logs you see at those times. But it should all be controlled with the same document click to start, pause and resume

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { fromEvent, Observable } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "my-app";
  pageClickObservable: Observable<Event> = fromEvent(document, "click");

  pause = false; // creating a variable to track the pause
  ngOnInit(): void {
    new Observable();

    this.pageClickObservable.pipe().subscribe(() => {
      this.pause = !this.pause; // change the pause status - true / false at alternative clicks
    });


 // mimicking observable sending data every second
    setInterval(() => {
      if (!this.pause) {
        // if not pause then execute the complete functions
        console.log("Click");
      } else {
        console.log("Do nothing");
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

This will simply console "Click" and "Do nothing" based on clicks.

For example, you have an observable sending data at every second, let's say, `setInterval`

If they share a common variable, such as `this.pause` in this case, then you can pause and resume easily.

Comment: That was clever, but only works with one emission. The observable emits a different specific value every second and sometimes 2 values. Those emissions can't be programatic since they could be anything. It could be a simple console log message, or a bunch of instructions that print on a page, or a notification, or a submit event, etc. This is part of a robot program. In your solution, the interval is conditional to the this.pause. If I put the intervals inside the condition, then it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

What I've done is to create an operator that delays the value based on a numerical property value.

### delayByProperty.ts

```
import {of, NEVER} from 'rxjs';
import {concatMap, delay} from 'rxjsoperators';

export function delayByProperty(propertyNameOfSecondsDelay:string) {
  return concatMap(obj => {
    const seconds:any = obj[propertyNameOfSecondsDelay];
    if (!seconds) {
      return of(obj);
    } else if (!Number.isFinite(seconds)) {
      throw new TypeError(`object property "${propertyNameOfSecondsDelay}" expected to be falsy or a number, was ${typeof(secondsDelay)} with value of ${secondsDelay}.`);
    } else if (seconds === -1) {
      return NEVER;
    } else if (seconds > 0) {
      return of(obj).pipe(
        delay(seconds * 1000)
      )
    }
  });
}
```

Now you can do

```
from([1,2,3,2,5,2,1]).pipe(
    map(n => {value:n, seconds:Number.parseFloat(n)}),
    delayByProperty('seconds')
)
```

Comment: Did you test this in my stackBlitz? I have no idea how to implement this in it

Comment: I copied that function into StackOverflow by hand because (for firewall reasons) I am not allowed to paste text into StackOverflow, nor access StackBlitz, from my machine, but let me try to edit with more explanation...

Answer (score -1):

When dealing with Observables, I've found it useful to think less like a programmer and more like a plumber. :-) Consider this:

```
function getObservableOfMsgs(click$) {
    //Array of objects that have whatever values you want in them, plus a property of "seconds" that contains the number of seconds you want to delay.
    const objs = [{msg:'1', seconds:1},{msg:'2', seconds:2},{msg:'TWO', seconds:2}];
    // observable we want per click.
    const perClick$ = from(objs).pipe(
        // map each object into an observable that delays, then emits the msg... and combine all of those observables to happen simultaneously.
        mergeMap(({msg, seconds}) => of(msg).pipe(delay(seconds * 1000)))
    );

    return click$.pipe(
        mapTo(perClick$)
    );
}
```

and now you'll have an observable that emits a pattern of messages per time you click.

So if you have a function called doSomethingWithMessage that takes a msg as a single argument and returned either null or a message you wanted to log as a debug message, you could do...

```
const unsubscribeFunctionInCaseINeedIt = getObservableOfMsgs(click$).pipe(
    tap(doSomethingWithMessage)
).subscribe(
    (d) => if (d !== null) console.debug(d),
    (e) => console.error(e),
    ()  => console.log('Complete!')
)
```

and then, until you call the returned function, it will all just "happen" as events stream through.

`from` and `of` are part of rxjs, so you should be able to `import {from, of} from 'rxjs'` Hopefully this automatically resolves because rxjs is part of Angular. Likewise, you might also have to `import {mergeMap, delay, mapTo, tap} from 'rxjs/operators'` or something, but I'm unable to access StackBlitz to confirm for you.

Comment: I've tried to implement this. There are too many holes in your answer. There is no clear explanation on how this solution can be implemented. If this is a solution that can only be understood by someone who is well versed in the technology, that person wouldn't be here asking a question to begin with.

Comment: Oof. I didn't mean to frustrate you. Thx for the feedback. Good luck.